# question about paralelepiped

Tags: geometry

please see  this link question 20

```
http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/documents/GRE-2010-MAT.pdf
```

problem is following   on figure 1 as you see there is parallelipiped   which has dimensions a,b,c and level of water h1  after turning   this figure new  dimensions and face is given.from    the existing choices  we should choose two of them to find what is h2(how much it is)  i need help how  to understand such problem when i will be given in future please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was fun to try to figure out a problem in a language that I do not understand.  Mathematics is truly international!  Well, not quite.  I would have had to concentrate harder if the labels had not been in the "roman" alphabet.

Note that the volume of water, in the picture on the left, is $abh_1$.

Note also that the volume of water, from the picture on the right, is $bch_2$.

We know that
$$abh_1=bch_2$$
and $b$ "cancels", in other words is irrelevant.

So we have
$$ah_1=ch_2$$.

Maybe, since we want $h_2$, we can solve for it.
We get
$$h_2=h_1\frac{a}{c}$$
this means that if we know $h_1$ and $a/c$, we know $h_2$. Thus, if I recall the choices correctly, knowing I and IV will let us find $h_2$.

Comment: you are right sorry  but in problem i have translated into english it is georgian languages(my country is georgia)

Comment: @user3196: I liked looking at all $20$ problems, and trying to figure out what familiar problem each corresponded to.  No need to be sorry!  I hope that the solution that I posted answers your question in enough detail.